# IME Android Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, ime, setting

I am trying to control the behavior off a an IME keyboard.
For instance the keyboard I downloaded uses combinations of characters(
say if you press "ß" + "π" it suggests "∑" 
I am making this example up. 
I would like to turn off this feature. 
Usually asian keyboards uses this feature.

I dont know the tech term for this. I looked at spannable but not very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keyboard doesn't have the option to turn it off, then it probably cannot be done. I don't think there is such a option in Android that applies to all keyboards.

Answer (score 2):

The Keyboard example that comes with the sdk shows how to do this, plus the keyboard that comes installed on the phone is open source.

Here is a [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master)

If you have any specific questions after looking these over I am sure you will be able to find answers here! Good luck!